# Travis-CI: Using environment variables in the deploy section of the .travis.yml file

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

I'm using `Travis-CI` to build my `Go` project and so far I used the `gimme` script with combination of travis go environment to cross-compile the project.

I switch to Go 1.5 that supports the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables to cross compiler without the need of other compilers or scripts.

My problems is that I'm using [Bintray deploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/bintray/) and my environment variables are not exposed in the deploy phase.

```
language: go

go:
  - 1.5

env:
    matrix:
       - GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64
       - GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
       - GOOS=linux GOARCH=386
       - GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64
before_script:
  - go get -d -v ./...

script:
  - go build -v ./...

before_deploy:
  - chmod +x ./prepare_bintray_deployment.sh
  - "./prepare_bintray_deployment.sh"

deploy:
  file: bintray_descriptors/${GOOS}_${GOARCH}.json
  provider: bintray
```

Note that before this change I was using the `GIMME_OS` and `GIMME_ARCH` environment variables and it worked fine and this makes me believe that Travis does support this.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I want to set the environment variable for my deploy in Travis CI too. Did you find out the solution to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me:

```yml
script:
  - # do some build stuff here
  - echo ${MY_VAR} > my_var.txt

before_deploy:
  - export MY_VAR=$(cat my_var.txt)

deploy:
  file: foo/bar_${MY_VAR}.json
  skip_cleanup: true
```

Essentially, you can't seem to access dynamic vars exported from the script section in the deploy section, but you *can* write them down (output to a file) and then access them later.

Comment: For others who encounter this solution. It seems that this workaround is no longer necessary. I had some difficulties by using `foo/bar_$MY_VAR.json`, which were solved when using `foo/bar_${MY_VAR}.json`